# Vector Data Loss When Leaving A Loop

Tags: c++, memory, vector, allocation

I wouldn't consider myself a programming newbie, but I have been struggling to understand vectors for the better part of six months now.

I've tried to use vectors in "production" code, but it never seems to function how I would expect. This example is one of the many problems I have with them, as is stated in the title, Vectors seem to mysteriously lose data after leaving a while loop. This will probably boil down to I'm simply using the vector all wrong, but I would like to think my process is at least somewhat sound. As you will notice, this is a vector of objects, which is probably pivotal to the issue as well.

In this example I've made, a char pointer with a random character inside of it is added to the vector, exactly ten times. Each time, the contents of the char pointer are erased and new content is added to ensure the data is unique. After leaving the loop, and starting another to print out the contents of the vector, none of the data that was just added to the vector is there anymore. Why?

Additionally, the initialization of the vector is non-standard from the examples I've seen, but seems to be the only way to get the vector to work without crashes.

Apologies for my poor formatting, the style in the code-block is not exactly how I format the code (Bracket spacing was screwed up slightly) Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main( int argc, char * argv[ ] ) {

    std::vector<char *> avector( 0 );
    avector.reserve( 400 );
    int counter = 0;
    char * place;
    bool ok;

    Back:
    if( counter == 10 ) {
        counter = 0;
        while( counter != 10 ){
            printf( "Element %d: %s\n", counter,  avector.at( counter ) );
            ++counter
        }
        ok = false;
    }
    while( counter != 10 ) {
        ok = true;
        place = (char *)malloc( 10 * sizeof( char ) );
        *place = (char)( ( rand( ) % 26 ) + 65 );
        printf("Pre-placement, element %d: %s\n", counter, place );
        avector.push_back( place );
        printf("Post-placement element %d: %s\n", counter, avector.at( counter ) );
        free( place );
        ++counter;

    }
    if( ok == true ) {
        goto Back;
    }


    exit( 0 );
}
```

Comment: ‘*this is a vector of objects*’ Er, no. It's a vector of `char*`.

Comment: The vector does not "lose" data. You delete it. You create a block of memory with "malloc" then push the address of it into the vector (note. you don't copy the memory, you just store the address there) and then you **delete** the memory with `free`. It seems to me you should more start learning about pointers more than vectors (or stop using malloc/free at all in c++. This is not C)

Comment: `goto Back;` Okay. I don't want to be mean. I'm sure you had the best of intentions when writing this code. But for the love of Turing, *why* would you write a `goto` statement????

Comment: What is the use case (real life problem) of your code / design? DO you really need to implement that approach?

Comment: @Xirema Shouldn't that be "for the love of Dijkstra"?

Comment: You can reformat your code automatically by piping it through `clang-format`. Pick a style and let the computer do the work for you!

Comment: Please don't forget to come back and choose up-vote useful answers and accept the one you found most helpful. It helps you, those trying to answer your questions, and the rest of the community as a whole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`place = (char *)malloc( 10 * sizeof( char ) );`
You're allocating data with malloc

`avector.push_back( place );`
You're pushing it to the vector

`free( place );`
And then, you delete it. So, the pointer is still in the vector, but the memory address does not belong anymore to you.

Also, you are programming in C++, not C, so don't use printf, goto, malloc and free.
And try to not use new and delete, use smart pointers instead (C++11)

Comment: I thought that the content was copied into the vector when you push it back. Thank you for clearing that up. I'll look into the smart pointers as well.

Answer (score 2):

The main bug in your code is that you're adding a pointer to your vector, but then invalidate the pointer you had stored in it.

```
place = (char *)malloc( 10 * sizeof( char ) );
avector.push_back( place );
free( place );   // <<--- BUG; you destroyed what's pointed to by place
```

The bug is that both `place` and the position to which `place` was added in `avector` (say, at `avector[avector.size() - 1]`) are pointing to the same memory location, so `free`ing `place` is the same as `free`ing the `avector[avector.size() - 1]` on a given iteration of the loop.

You've basically pulled the rug from under your own feet.

I think a simpler example can help you see more clearly. This is a refactored version of your code, using proper C++ instead of a mix of C++ and C:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char * argv[ ] ) {
    vector<char *> my_char_pointers;

    cout << "Filling up vector ..." << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        cout << "Adding address of " << char(65 + i) << " to vector ..." << endl;
        my_char_pointers.push_back(new char(65 + i));
    }

    cout << "Printing vector ..." << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < my_char_pointers.size(); ++i)
        cout << my_char_pointers.at(i) << endl;

    cout << "Deleting char pointer vector elements ..." << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < my_char_pointers.size(); ++i)
        delete my_char_pointers[i];

    cout << "Printing vector of now-INVALID pointers ..." << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < my_char_pointers.size(); ++i)
        cout << my_char_pointers.at(i) << endl;

    cout << "Removing the now invalid pointers from vector ..." << endl;
    my_char_pointers.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

Running it in my Linux PC, you get the following output:

```
$ g++ -o test test.cpp
$ ./test 
Filling up vector ...
Adding address of A to vector ...
Adding address of B to vector ...
Adding address of C to vector ...
Adding address of D to vector ...
Adding address of E to vector ...
Printing vector ...
A
B
C
D
E
Deleting char pointer vector elements ...
Printing vector of now-INVALID pointers ...

 ��
`��
@��
���
Removing the now invalid pointers from vector ...
```

A few differences to notice between your version and mine, including bug fix and other details:

1. I create, but don't `delete`, the `vector` inputs inside the same loop (this is the fix);
2. Your code is hard to follow, making errors more difficult to catch/debug;
3. It uses `new` and `delete`, which are the proper ways to allocate/deallocate memory in C++ (`malloc` and friends are for C)
4. It uses `cout` from `<iostream>`, which is the proper way to print output in C++ (`printf` is for C)
5. It uses properly structured code and does *not* rely on `goto`[1], which leads to spaghetti code;
6. And my code is *easier to follow/understand*, making any errors easier to find/fix

You need to work on your code structure, simplified logic, and other details if you really want to come across as not being a "programming newbie".

Also notice that you don't really have a `vector` of "objects"; you have a vector of *pointers to `char`s*. The `vector` named `my_char_pointers` is an object, but its contents are *primitive* types. (Yes, terminology does make a difference.)

[1] Why on Dijkstra's name would you use `goto` statements? They cause lots of headaches to yourself and those that will inevitably need to read your code in the future.